# Sophos interfering with NodeJS processes on Mac OSX Big Sur

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Ever since I upgraded to Big Sur, I've noticed that Sophos has begun to interfere dramatically whenever I run Jest tests. CPU usage for Sophos spikes to around 400% when running even a modest Jest test program, with 71 tests currently taking 98.6 seconds to run. After the Jest process completes, Sophos goes back to sleep and no longer takes up substantial resources.

I run these tests from my terminal using Node. My hypothesis is that the problem is actually between Node and Sophos, and it's just exacerbated by the way that Jest runs its tests.

Has anyone come across this problem before, and is there anything I can do to convince Sophos to leave Node alone?

For what it's worth, the tests themselves are bog-standard JS and React unit tests, with the React tests written using React Testing Library.

[image]

Comment: Seeing similar behavior with sophos on m1 Mac. 10x the time to copy files and cpu pegged during file copies. Have you found any solution or heard from sophos on how to resolve?

Comment: Same happens to me too. I tried on a machine without sophos and tests runs in 30 seconds. With Sophos tests runs in 5 minutes!!!

Comment: I get even worse behavior, just running `npm ci` a few times, my whole computer becomes unresponsive to the point of unusability.  `top` shows sophos processes using several 100% of cpu.  Even disabling realtime file/network scans, computer will become unresponsive.